# Sqlalchemy overwrite field from association table

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two entities, `Player` and `Game` and the relationship between them is many to many.
Both `Player` and the connection between `Player` and `Game` (`PlayerGame`) have a score

```
class Player(db.Model):
 id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
 score = db.Column(db.Float)
 name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)

class Game(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(45))

class PlayerGame(db.Model):
  player_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('players.id'), primary_key=True)
  game_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('games.id'), primary_key=True)
  score = db.Column(db.Float)

  player = db.relationship("Player", backref="games")
  game = db.relationship("Game", backref="players")
```

I want to write a query using sqlalchemy that given a game id, returns all related players, but their score will be overwritten by score of the game

So far my query looks like this

```
Player.query.join(PlayerGame, and_(
    PlayerGame.player_id == Player.id,
    PlayerGame.game_id == game_id))\
.options(contains_eager(Player.games))
```

I was thinking about changing `Player.score` and `PlayerGame.score` label names, or exluding `Player.score` but none of the above really seemed to work

It is possible to do it after the query in python code, but ideally, I want it to be part of the query

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted your model a little bit, and then below used a query that is not delivering back a "Player" object because the result is an attribute from the player and an attribute from PlayerGame:

```
class Player(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  score = db.Column(db.Float)
  name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
  playergames = db.relationship('PlayerGame', backref='player', lazy=True, 
     cascade="delete")

class Game(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(45))
  playergames = db.relationship('PlayerGame', backref='game', lazy=True, 
  cascade="delete")

class PlayerGame(db.Model):
  player_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('player.id'), primary_key=True)
  game_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('game.id'), primary_key=True)
  score = db.Column(db.Float)

p = Player(name = "Hoffmann", score = 7.5)
p1 = Player(name = "Fink", score = 4.5)
db.session.add(p)
db.session.add(p1)

g = Game(name = "VfB")
g1 = Game(name = "HSV")

db.session.add(g)
db.session.add(g1)

pg = PlayerGame(player = p, game = g, score = 1.5)
pg1 = PlayerGame(player = p1, game = g, score = 3.5)
db.session.add(pg)
db.session.add(pg1)
db.session.commit()    

playergamescores = db.session.query(Player.name, 
    PlayerGame.score).join(Player).filter(PlayerGame.game_id == g.id).all()   
print(playergamescores)
```

Output is then [('Hoffmann', 1.5), ('Fink', 3.5)]

Comment: But you get only player name and score, I want to have the Player object
Maybe I should get player_id and score and then fetch the players by their ids